# How to apply alternate row style in listbox in window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi I am New to Window phone 7, I have a Problem for Applying style to alternate row color in  listbox in Window phone 7. Please Help Me.

Comment: You should post some of the code you are having trouble with, and explain the actual problem. [See here for making good questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: @Vijay Chavda : Can you provide the code you used to apply alternate colors for rows in windows phone app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While WPF has an `ALternationCount` property that supports this, Silverlight, both the web version and WP7, do not. The easiest way to create this effect in Silverlight is to set the bacground colour of your item via a value converter. See the following thread:

[Alternating background colors for ListBox rows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/40ab4d18-6ded-40f3-a0b3-a2688981ec99/)

Comment: Hi Everyone i got the solution from the below link      
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/14345.aspx

Comment: Cool - have you upvoted / marked the above response as the answer?

Comment: The link in your answer is broken/not valid. Could you provide the correct one ?

Comment: Just an FYI, this whole solution is flawed because you need to consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532881/alternating-row-background-color-for-listbox-rows-in-window-phone-7

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Item_LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        StackPanel ItemRef = sender as StackPanel;      // get the reference to the control
        SolidColorBrush brush1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0));      //base colour
        SolidColorBrush brush2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));  //alternate colour

        if (_useAlternate)
            ItemRef.Background = brush1;
        else
            ItemRef.Background = brush2;

        _useAlternate = !_useAlternate;
    }
```